# Similar to a Matching Game

Tags: android

I want to do something, where I will have 4 buttons. There will only be a success if 2 matching buttons are pressed. At the moment I only know how to handle one button click, but I don't know how to make it so that if I press a button, and then afterwards press another button.. a fail or success occurs depending on the button pressed.

What would  I use to go on about implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you want to detect simultaneous press of two buttons, you can set an `OnTouchListener` for the buttons and detect when each one is pressed or released. With a little bookkeeping, you can then detect whether the user presses two matching buttons at the same time.

If you want to track successive button clicks, then you need some way of identifying which button was last clicked. There are a couple of ways to do this. One is to assign a different `OnClickHandler` (or a different `android:onClick` method) to each button. Another way (better, in my opinion) is to assign a unique tag value to each button. In XML, the tag will be a string, which you can then parse into an int value using `Integer.parseInt()`; in code it can be an Integer. Then your click handler determines the button's tag value and uses that in the program logic.

The way you would use this is as follows. Define a field in your game class for the last button clicked. Before any buttons are clicked, it should have the value -1 (indicating no button). Then when you get a button click, determine its identity (either from the tag or by which click handler was invoked). Check whether the last button and the current button form a correct sequence. If not, then set the last button to the current button.

Comment: I don't want simultaneous button presses. I want a button, and the next consecutive button press I want something to actually happen. So it remembers the first button press, and does something based on the second button press. I hope you follow :S

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current button id on clicked event, So you can maintain a integer value for previously clicked button. and compare currently button click with the previous button  clicked and do your task..

Comment: I'm fairly new to programming.How would i go about doing this?

Currently most my button presses case R.id.button: this.startActivity(nextActivity); Thats what I am currently doing. How would i maintain an interger value?

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment that each button starts a new Activity, you may want to consider using a single Activity, and simply change the view.

Particularly if a particular button click in the last activity affects the new activity, it seems they should really be the same activity.

However, if you really want to use Multiple Activities you have several options:

1. Store the last button pressed in SharePreferences.
2. Store the last button pressed in a file, or SQLite database
3. when you start the new activity, use intent.putExtra() to store the last button pressed,  so the new activity can access it through getIntent().getExtra()